# number format exception error handling

Tags: java, loops, numberformatexception

I have a string array which is filled with numbers. Any unset element in the array will be `null` by default. I'm then looping through this array, parsing the Strings to their `int` values, but I'm running into a `NumberFormatException` when the loop reaches a `null` element.

I don't know in advance how many numbers will be in the array, so I'm using a large array to make sure there is enough space to hold all of the Strings.

How can I stop the loop before it reaches a `null` element?

```
for (int x = 1 ; x < array1.length ; x++){
    int newnode = Integer.parseInt(array1[x]);
    //searching in matrix
    // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: Using a `List` instead of an array may avoid the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the number of elements that you will be handling in advance each time, then use a dynamically-sized collection instead of a fixed-size array.

Change the code that populates your collection to use a `List<String>` instead of a `String[]`. Lists are dynamically-sized, and will continually grow as you add more elements to it. There won't be any `null` elements returned when you iterate unless you specifically add them in the first place, so your code will never attempt to parse a `null` value.

This change would then allow you to iterate over the List like so:

```
for (String number : array1) { // You might want to rename array1 to something meaningful...
    int newNode = Integer.parseInt(number);
    // Do other stuff
}
```

You can still maintain a separate index variable if you need to do so, it would just be declared and incremented manually, rather than as part of the loop construct.

Comment: A try catch block should be used around `Integer.parseInt()` because it can throw `NumberFormatException` for many reasons and you probably don't want the program to halt then.

Comment: @MichaelShopsin That depends on the contents of the list. If you have control over the source and the code that creates the list you can ensure that only valid data is inserted into it in the first place. In that instance, you could argue that a failure at this point is indicative of a more fundamental error earlier in the code. It also may indicate that the data is in an invalid state and that processing should not continue further. If invalid data can be ignored, then by all means catch the exception and continue processing...if it can't, don't.

Comment: Nov In my experience `Integer.parseInt()` is that it's overly sensitive so I usually catch the exception and then try to parse the number another way.

Comment: @MichaelShopsin But if you've ensured that the data is valid at point of entry, then catching the NFE later on is as good as dead code. I prefer when possible to reject the bad data quickly, rather than let it live in the application to fail at some unknown point later on.

Comment: Sometimes I'm reading a file or other input where I do not get to control what is coming in, and don't want to stop the whole input on every single error. When I read a series of XML files I don't want to stop on a single number error since they will not make an important difference to the results. There was a good discussion in [How to avoid Number Format Exception in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19749081/369446) about fully validating numbers in strings.

Comment: @MichaelShopsin Oh it's certainly not something that is always possible to do - I'm not claiming that. As with all things in code, the best solution depends on your use-case; sometimes you need to catch the exception, sometimes you don't. It's for the OP to decide if that's required for their particular scenario