# Why do I get a "Number Format Exception"?

Tags: java, swing, number-formatting

I have this code and in it there is a function to convert binary to decimal. It sets the text of a JTextArea to the result and appends the result to a different JTextArea. The former works fine but the latter causes the above mentioned exception to appear. This is my code below. Pls help.

```
JButton numerical = new JButton("BIN->NUM");
    numerical.setFont(small);
    numerical.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Display.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Display.getText(), 2)));
            try {
                Memory.append(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Display.getText(), 2))); 
                Memory.append("\n");
            } catch (Exception ie) {
                Memory.append(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Display.getText(), 2)));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: provide the stacktrace please

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid Number Format Exception in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499523/how-to-avoid-number-format-exception-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, the first works fine. At this point

```
Display.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Display.getText(), 2)));
```

The input value to `parseInt()` is in binary form and the conversion works.  However the `setText()` replaces that binary value with the decimal equivalent.  Then when you attempt

```
Memory.append(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Display.getText(), 2)));
```

the number is in decimal format and the second conversion fails because you specified base 2 and it expects the number to be in binary.